# Back slashes in Android NDK path keeps QT application from deploying

Tags: android, windows, qt, android-ndk, qt-creator

I'm able to compile my application in Windows but when I try to debug on my tablet I get this error.

```
/usr/bin/sh: line 1: C:androidndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib: No such file or directory
```

I figured the problem is that under Tools->Options->Android the path to my android NDK is listed as C:\android\ndk so I tried replacing the back slashes with forward slashes.  But when I do this the error is still there and when I open my Android options the back slashes are back.

Comment: *I tried replacing the back slashes with forward slashes* - what file did you change?

Comment: Does your path really contain C:androidndk?

Comment: There was no file, I changed an option under Tools->Options->Android.  And no, my path contains C:\android\ndk.  It looks like the Cygwin shell is removing the back slashes so I'm trying to replace "\" with "/".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got to the root of the problem but I created a new project and that worked just fine.  Since the path to the ndk looked messed up I thought there was a problem with my QtCreator setup but simply starting a new project fixed this issue.

Comment: Strangely, this does not help me. When I try to build my C++ library for Android, I see exactly the same issue even if NDK lies in C: root: `/usr/bin/sh: C:android-ndk-r10e/`